# What is the purpose of _init() and _fini() in the GCC toolchain?

Tags: arm, bare-metal

I'm writing a bare metal ARM program in C and C++, using the linker and startup scripts provided by CMSIS_5. To get C++ global constructors etc. working, the linker must iterate through and execute the function pointers located in the memory between `__init_array_start` and `__init_array_end` which are defined in the linker script.

To do this, the `__libc_init_array()` function is called ([init.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob_plain;f=newlib/libc/misc/init.c;hb=HEAD)) from (I think) [crt0.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob_plain;f=libgloss/arm/crt0.S;hb=cd5e7e2d8271d8d4b976eaa42c69770d94c67a74).
This function calls `_init()`
However, my program only compiles (undefined reference) if I manually define `_init()`, and I have done so as such:

```
void _init(void) {};
```

My global constructors are called by `__libc_init_array()` just fine. So, what is the purpose of `_init()`? Is this simply for custom user initialisation code? Or am I calling these functions incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

On bare-metal ARM, the `_init` function should already be provided by gcc. It's comprised of code fragments from multiple `.init` sections that get concatenated by the linker. [`crti.o`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/config/arm/crti.S;h=eec2ace84593d54a898419f99193df149419b0c1;hb=a7eb0564c3060418b5ca68c2806ad74f73384fd0) provides the `_init` symbol and the function prolog. [`crtn.o`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/config/arm/crtn.S;h=7551012d17fc164ef92ec0d28fa13849609bb653;hb=a7eb0564c3060418b5ca68c2806ad74f73384fd0) provides the function epilog. There's nothing in the middle, but historically there would be code fragments that do initialization or call constructors. Now constructors are handled as function pointers that get called after `_init` rather than as code fragments that form `_init`.

Normally the start files `crti.o` and `crtbegin.o` are linked before your files and `crtend.o` and `crtn.o` after them. If you're getting a link failure due to an undefined reference to `_init`, it's probably because you're using the `-nostartfiles` option. That should be fine as long as you provide a replacement for the parts that are used, which should just be an empty `_init` function in this case.

The default `_init` function also requires a `KEEP (*(.init))` at an appropriate location in your linker script since only the first part of `_init` that's provided by `crti.o` is actually referenced. The same goes for `.fini`/`_fini` , although you'll never notice in the likely case that your application never exits.

Answer (score 1):

> My global constructors are called by __libc_init_array() just fine. So, what is the purpose of _init()?

The are probably the same thing.

---

These function names are tool dependant.  There are no shared libraries in the setup you have. However, the referenced 'crt0.S' has,

```
#ifdef HAVE_INITFINI_ARRAY
#define _init   __libc_init_array
#define _fini   __libc_fini_array
#endif
... [removed code for brevity] ...
#ifdef __USES_INITFINI__
    /* Some arm/elf targets use the .init and .fini sections
       to create constructors and destructors, and for these
       targets we need to call the _init function and arrange
       for _fini to be called at program exit.  */
... [removed code for brevity] ...
    bl  FUNCTION (_init)
#endif
```

In some systems, `_init()` is not table base.  It depends on the compiler's configuration and version.  There is also other 'init' methods.  Also, if you are never going to `exit()`, there is no need for '.fini()' or other related functionality.  This is common for a bare metal embedded system.  So, you don't need `.fini` unless you make some sort of 'shutdown' support that uses it.